# Android Jtwitter, authentication issues

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, oauth-2.0, jtwitter

Hello I am having difficulty using the JTwitter functions to authenticate with my twitter application. I always get a "TwitterException"

Here is my method

```
OAuthSignpostClient oauthClient = new OAuthSignpostClient(consumerKey, 
            privateKey, "oob");
```

a) I don't know what the "oob" value SHOULD be, it is the "callbackURL" and in my application on twitter it says `"callBack URL: none"`  so I have tried putting `"none"`, `"None"`, and `null`  where `"oob"` with no differing results.

then the rest is boilerplate

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse(oauthClient.authorizeUrl().toString()));
    startActivity(i);
    // get the pin
    String v = oauthClient.askUser("Please enter the verification PIN from Twitter");
    oauthClient.setAuthorizationCode(v);
    // Store the authorisation token details for future use
    String[] accessToken = oauthClient.getAccessToken();
    // Next time we can use new OAuthSignpostClient(OAUTH_KEY, OAUTH_SECRET, 
    //        accessToken[0], accessToken[1]) to avoid authenticating again.

    EditText twitterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.twitterText);
    twitterText.getText();

    // Make a Twitter object
    Twitter twitter = new Twitter(null, oauthClient);
    // Print Daniel Winterstein's status
    //System.out.println(twitter.getStatus("winterstein"));
    // Set my status
    twitter.setStatus(twitterText.getText());
```

at this point, I'm simply not sure on how to make this work. Wish I could be more verbose about it, but it has something to do with the authentication. Online things I've seen haven't been helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this ***as your callback url***:

```
OAuthSignpostClient oauthClient = 
    new OAuthSignpostClient(consumerKey, privateKey, "callback://twitter");
```

---

***Remember!*** After:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
```

Do the following

***override*** `onResume()` to get the verification code

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (this.getIntent()!=null && this.getIntent().getData()!=null){
        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith("callback://twitter")) {
            //Do whatever you want
            //usually use uri.getQueryParameter(someString);
            //test what could be someString using Log.v("",uri.toString());
            //you want the Authorization code which is a couple of numbers
            //so you could use oauthClient.setAuthorizationCode(v); 
            //and finally initialise Twitter
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `uri.getQueryParameterNames()` to get the parameter `String` names.

---

@BobVork

I'd just like to add that you'll need to have a callback URL set in the Settings tab for your Twitter app (on twitter.com).

It doesn't even matter what you put in the field, but if it's empty, callback urls will not work.

Comment: I'd just like to add that you'll need to have a callback URL set in the Settings tab for your Twitter app (on twitter.com). It doesn't even matter what you put in the field, but if it's empty, callback urls will not work. This took me about an hour to find out, so I thought this might save somebody else some time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's the problem, but it seems like you never set the user name for the twitter object.

Comment: I thought the point of oath was so that the user doesn't have to put their username in or something... much less hard code it? The concept kind of confuses, my first intuition was that username goes somewhere, but then the twitter object seemed to not require it and someone oath would take care of it

Comment: I am not that familiar with twitter APIs, but everywhere I looked (even in the example you took the code from), even when oAuth was used, the user name was used too. You can keep it once and then use it when needed, you don't have to read it from some TextView each time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know how it is with the Jtwitter API and I don't know enough Java at this point to really understand the inner workings of this code, but have you tried, instead of `NULL` or `None`, to try `?` instead. That is the callback used with the restful API when making calls from Javascript. Try it out.